# Python check if entry exists in online web glossary

Tags: python, html, urllib

I would like to develop a Python script which can search the following web glossary to see if an entry exists or not.

[AMS Glossary](https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Welcome)

The url for word definitions is:
glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/[word]

If the word is defined in the glossary, a definition is returned (i.e. https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Pressure)

If the word does not exist in the glossary, a webpage saying as such is returned (i.e. https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Peanuts)

My idea is that I can take some word, look at the html page for the url using that word at the end, and if it matches the "no word exists" web page, I know that word does not exist in the glossary.

I do not actually need to pull definitions from the web pages, I just need to know if there is a entry for it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to check the content of the page. pages that don't exist, like the `Peanuts` page, return a `404` while good ones return a `200`.

so you just have to check the return code
something like

```py
word = "Pressure"

page = requests.get(f"https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/{word}")
if page.status_code == 200:
  print("entry exists")
else:
  print("bad page")
```